# Getting current Windows user in Blazor Server for AD auth

Tags: c#, active-directory, single-sign-on, blazor-server-side, .net-core-3.1

I want to create an intranet application with Blazor server where the logged in windows user gets automatically authenticated against "classic" AD when accessing the site. Like single sign on. My problem is that I am unable to access the current Windows user.

I tried via `HttpContextAccessor` but the user is null. This is my test code. Later I plan on using code from this doku for authentication: [Offical MS Doku](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Is this even the right approach or do I have to write a small Blazor wasm app to hand this over via a signalR connection?

```
public partial class Counter
{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        username = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
        {
             username = "user = null"; 
        }
    }

    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    [Inject]
    private IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; set; } = default!;

    private string username = default!;
}
```

I ofc added `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` to the `startup.cs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you enable windows auth on the IIS server
During design time in visual studio, under project properties->Debug, enable windows auth.

And then the identity is available with:

```
var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
var user = authState.User;

if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
..etc
```

Comment: Yes you understand me correctly. Thanks. I tried this code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 under "Expose the authentication state as a cascading parameter" and checked enable windows auth under properties->Debug. I put the razor code in index.razor. Did i miss something?

but still nothing. Not even if i run in debug mode locally. user.Identity.Name is always null and Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.

Comment: I hate to leave "half-thought answers", but due to that I have little spare time and so on... 
Take a look at this articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio  
https://medium.com/@vaibhavrb999/windows-authentication-authorization-in-blazor-application-144d23dd90be

Comment: I solved it. I set windows auth to true but forgot to turn off anonymous auth.